# Find total time spent by user on the website.

Tags: mysql, django, orm, modal-dialog

How to get Sum of Difference of two fields in Django ORM?

I have a modal where user activities are mapped. I add Time when user login, and add time when user logs out.

I need the difference of these two fields and then all the instances together to get Total time spent by user on the site.

```
User.objects.filter(**user_kwargs).annotate(
            visit_count=Count('visit_history'),
            time_on_site=Avg('visit_history__time_on_site'),
        ).filter(visit_count__gt=0).order_by('-time_on_site')
```

How to find total time spent by user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cant do that with django orm.

Not without using at least raw query anyway.

Let me repeat things so you can verify, if i understood you correctly.

You want to select the sum of difference betweem model.field_a and model.field_b.

Django orm only allows you to select model fields, not their differences or sums. If you want to use django orm here, then create additonal model and use raw query and aggregate function. Raw query would be the one that creates ghost field, by having something like

```
SELECT ..., row.one_value - row.second_value AS row.somecolumn, ... FROM foo ...
```

But since you already need to get down and dirty with pure sql, then i suggest you skip the orm completely and use transactions and connections and just pure sql to get what you need.

Comment: Thank you @odif :)
i think this is exactly i need to do.